# How to store the request body into a variable in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to store the request body in a variable that I can use it again.
I am trying to do it via jsr223.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. "via JSR223" what? [PreProcesor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)? [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)? [Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)? [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener)? [Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer)?
2. For which [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) you need to store the data as the instructions will be different?

The "universal" solution would be:

```
vars.put('foo', ctx.getPreviousResult().getSamplerData())
```

which will store the body of the previous request into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with the name of `${foo}`

However you might want to adapt it according to your needs.

References:

- `ctx` aka [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- `vars` aka [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- More information on JMeter API shortcuts available for JSR223 test elements: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: 1.PostProcessor
2.HTTP request

Comment: Then my answer is applicable